# using json encode on an Object with Escaped characters ( double quotes )

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am using [mysqli::real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) on the inputs received from my forms before sending them to the database .
in another page i am receiving these data and converting each row of data into JSON using `json_encode`
then i am sending them into front-end as response :

```
        $usersInstance = new usersRepository();
        $users = $usersInstance->allUsers();  
ob_start();  
 foreach ($users as $index => $user) {

                $userObj = (object) [];
                $userObj->id = $user['id'];
                $userObj->email = $user['email'];
                $userObj->displayname = $user['display_name'];
                $userObj->grade = $user['grade'];
                $userJson = json_encode($userObj);
                $userBox = <<<HTML
            <div class="user-box" data-userjson={$userJson}>

<div class="user-cell " >
    <span> {$user['email']} </span>
</div>

<div class="user-id-holder"  style="visibility:hidden;width:0px;height:0px;overflow:hidden;display:inline-block">
 {$user['id']}
</div>

<div class="user-cell" >
    <span>{$user['display_name']}</span>
</div>
<div class="user-cell " >
    <span>سطح دسترسی : {$user['grade']}</span>
</div>
<div class="user-cell">
    <span class="user-action-btn" data-action="edit"><span>ویرایش</span></span>
    <span class="user-action-btn" data-action="delete"><span>حذف</span></span>
</div>
</div>
HTML;

                echo $userBox;
            }
            $renderedContent = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
```

then i want to access these JSONs in javascript like this

```
let UserBox = $(this).parent('div').parent('div.user-box');
let userObj = $(UserBox).data('userjson');
```

The problem is that when i try access object i get errors and undefined because escaped double quotes represent as `"`
  and it makes the object an invalid JSON , see example output below :
`{"id":"32","email":"test3@gmail.com","displayname":"test'and'more'test"","grade":"2"}`
**displayname propert** has a value that contains **double quote** which cause object to be invalid.

My question is that how can i keep escaped characters escaped when i am using the JSON   i want to display the values in html and they become `"` when are printed .  so actual problem is that how can i seperate `"` and `&quot` ?

Comment: Please don't use `mysqli::real_escape_string`. You should be using prepared statements. If you want to escape the quotes to be used in HTML context use `htmlentities()` on output, but not when inserting the data into the database.

Comment: does it result in any kind of problem if i insert HTML Encoded strings in database ?

Comment: Yes. You are basically mutilating your data. What if you want to use it in context other than HTML? What if you want to use the values in `WHERE` query?

Comment: you are right , but one more question , does `htmlentities()` prevent SQL Injection ? i am asking for if i don't want to use prepared statements

Comment: **Definitely not!** `htmlentities()` prevents XSS at best, but is completely useless against SQL injection. The only correct way to protect against SQL injection is to make sure that your SQL is constant and doesn't include any variable input. Send the data separately from your SQL by binding it through prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) to escape the quotes and turn them into `&quot;` when handling your form data. Then when you get the data back and use `json_encode` on it, there should be real double quotes around your JSON stuff and the quotes going in the HTML are `&quot;`, which will be properly parsed and rendered.

Comment: thank you , this solved my problem , how ever this also requires to decode them in java script using [this trick](https://gomakethings.com/decoding-html-entities-with-vanilla-javascript/)

Comment: @ImanEmadi You don't need tricks for that--use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse your JSON.